# Typo3 multiple domain record on one page

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have this problem:

If I put two or more Domain records on one site (because of an alias), each link in the menu and/or breadcrumb links to the first domain record only.

Domain name for example: site.com Alias for example: beta.site.com

If I am on http://beta.site.com every link links to site.com

My config:

```
absRefPrefix = /
config.baseURL #not set up
```

I have tried to configure the base URL according to the HTTP host this way:

```
[globalString = ENV:http_HOST=www.site.com]
config.baseURL =www.site.com
```

The base URL was right, but every link still links to the first domain record.

Always prepend this domain in links in the properties of the domain record is not checked

The same in Backend: Preview of page always shows the preview of first domain in list ... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that you will have duplicate content problems if you're delivering the same content from two domains.

As soon as you're using Domain Records, the first domain record is taken for generating Typolinks. As far as I know, there is no need to use domain records, so if you remove them and use the TypoScript condition for the baseURL, it should work - even if I don't recommend it.

Domain records are normally used if you have multiple sites in one installation where each domain is pointing to another site. Example structure:

- TYPO3 Root Page

  - My Portal (holding TypoScripts that affects all sites) - no domain record

    - myfirstsite.tld - Domain record myfirstsite.tld
    - mysecondsite.tld - Domain record mysecondsite.tld

You can also use domain records for nested sites (but as far as I know you need a manual RealURL configuration to have it working):

- TYPO3 Root Page

  - mywebsite.tld - Domain record mywebsite.tld

    - About us
    - Products
    - A special site inside with an own domain - Domain record myspecialsite.tld
    - Contact

So domain records are not useless at all, but not useful for your use-case.

It is possible to add more than one domain record because you might want to be able to switch them quickly (move www.mysite.tld up when dev.mysite.tld is first) or you want to define some redirections without htaccess rules.

Comment: sorry for my English: It works, but only if typo3 is not behind reverse proxy, as in our case (I think it, because on dev. enviroment it works, but on server behind nginx it doesnt works). And what about nested domains??? I dont understand, why if i use domain records typolinks get the first (why doesnt decide according to http host? eg). So why is the possibility to add more domain records to one page in Typo3. Wierd ...

Comment: because "normally" you use domain-records as entry points in a tree like lorenz described in his first example. So if you want two domains pointing to the same tree (even www.* and * are a usecase) you need to put multiple domain-records on one page.